# how to put files on the localhost

Tags: php, macos, apache2, localhost, httpd.conf

So, if you guys have any macs then you know that PHP 5 and Apache 2 are already installed, but disabled for privacy reasons. I just know used terminal to enable Apache server and PHP. It told me that I need to transfer it to the localhost or root-directory, but I i'm unaware of how to go about that. So, please help!

Comment: usually it should be `/var/www` check if you have that folder.

Comment: read this: [install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion)

Comment: I have a mac os x 10.8.5 or 10.8.4

Comment: all answers are in `httpd.conf` file

Comment: I do have that folder I checked terminal but how do I put the files there or transfer them?

Comment: it says this "The alias “httpd.conf” can’t be opened because the original item is in the Trash."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transfer files to localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237148/how-to-transfer-files-to-localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation is from the official PHP website and tells you everything you need to know wbout using the default installation on OSX: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php